# Dependencies ignored and deleted from package-lock.json after npm install

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dependencies, npm-install, package-lock.json

I'm trying to run an **JS Chrome** extension from a cloned repository. The problem occurs after I run **npm install** where some of the dependencies in the **package-lock.json** file gets deleted and essentially ignored. This causes the project to miss many of the modules necessary for it to run.

I've tried using **npm ci** but it still has the same problem. I've also tried using yarn and **yarn check** but to no avail. What is the problem here? Why doesn't **npm** install all the dependencies in **package-lock.json** file without having to delete some of them?

[image]

Comment: Are you using the latest npm? I've found this solves issues earlier versions have.

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure I am using the most recent version of npm.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.